# how to name colums?

Tags: pandas, rename

I have a pandas Data Frame where some of the id's are repeated a few times. I've written this code:

```
df = df["id"].value_counts()
```

and got this output

[image]

What should I do to get something like in the following image?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `value_counts` set `id` as index and return a series. So you want to do something like `df['id'].value_counts().to_frame(name='B')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quang Hoang answered, `value_counts` set the column you count as the index. Therefore in order to get the `id` and the count as columns, you need to do 2 things:

- Make the counts as column - `to_frame(name='B')`
- Reset the index to make the ids another column which we'll rename to the desired name: `.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'A'})`

So in one line it'll be:

```
df = df["id"].value_counts().to_frame(name='B').reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'A'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is:

```
col = list(["A", "B")]
df.columns = col
```

Comment: @ acm151130 the same